# Advanced methods of theoretical condensed matter

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations

I am looking for an online course devoted to the advanced methods of theoretical condensed matter physics. It is good if the course offers free materials like lectures, homework assignments etc.

Things to be covered:

- Functional integral methods
- equilibrium and non-equilibrium Green's functions
- Perturbation theory and Feynman diagrams
- Applications to bosonic and fermionic systems

Comment: Hi Nex_Friedrich,  Res. recom. questions are restricted on Phys.SE because they tend to be _too broad_  _primarily opinion-based_ list questions. I'm closing this list question as a _duplicate,_ not because it is an exact duplicate, but to point in the right direction.